# Is there a way to generate the INotifyPropertyChanged helper with Resharper after having implemented the interface?

Tags: c#, resharper, inotifypropertychanged

I have several classes that implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

I'm now using Resharper and want to add the following standard code snippet to these classes:

```
[NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

The simplest solution I found so far is to delete the

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

and implement the interface again, this time with the helper. Is there an easier way?

Comment: You could use [snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms165392.aspx) as an alternative.

Comment: @Corak Maybe you got me wrong. I want to use Resharper but cannot get the INotifyPropertChangedHelper snippet inserted after the interface has already been implemented.

Comment: I did get you. I just suggested that if that snippet is all you want and don't find a way to get it via resharper, then maybe using the built-in snippets mechanic could be an alternative to get a similar result.

Comment: @Corak I just discovered the solution. I'll have a look at the snippets anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press `Alt+Return` over the property, you get the chance to create the helper.

[image: Screenshot]
N.b. the Mouse is over `PropertyChanged`.